# how can I detect change in brightness in android?

Tags: android, brightness

I am trying to develop a simple app that can monitor the value of current screen brightness and update the value when the brightness is changed by a user.

Here is my code to get the current brightness.

```
try {
    float curBrightnessValue=android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
        getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        System.out.println(curBrightnessValue);
} catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I am struggling with updating the value.
How can I update the value when there is a change in brightness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you:

```
ContentObserver contentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
  @Override
  public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    int a = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 0);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Brightness value: "+ a);
  }
};
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS),
    false, contentObserver);
```

Callback is attached to receive the changes when content are changed